# Running ndb server.js error and cant install chromium

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I can't install `chromium` with `ndb server.js`
How can i fix this?

[image]

```
ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r624492!
Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/.local-data/download-mac-624492.zip'
  -- ASYNC --
    at BrowserFetcher.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/helper.js:108:27)
    at downloadChromium (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/find_chrome.js:194:50)
    at findChrome (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/find_chrome.js:241:32)
    at Object.launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/carlo.js:594:42)
    at launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/lib/launcher.js:23:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/ndb.js:35:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12) {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/.local-data/download-mac-624492.zip'
}
unhandledRejection TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'executablePath')
    at findChrome (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/find_chrome.js:242:43)
    at async Object.launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/carlo.js:594:36)
    at async launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/lib/launcher.js:23:11)
```

I try with `sudo npm run` debug, it works but chromium is downloading forever.

[image]